# Knowing the rendered email from within the layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

From within the mailer layout (`views/layouts/mailer.html.erb`) is there a way to know which email it is rendering?

Something like `controller_name` and `action_name` in the view.

Comment: not very elegant, but you could pass it along as an instance variable... or have another layout for another type of email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mailer.class` and `mailer.action_name`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<%= mailer.class %>`

Comment: That is the equivalent of `controller_name` but I also need `action_name`. Thanks